# The app.routing.module.ts file missing in Ionic Project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm setting up a new ionic project using the following command :

```
ionic start myapp blank --type=ionic-angular
```

My problem is that in the project there is no app.routing.module.ts file as usual. What is the actual problem . What have i done wrong ?

My ionic version is 5.2.8.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I am using Angular CLI: 11.0.2 Node: 12.18.3,
The `app.routing.module.ts` file was missing, by applying the command down below:

```
ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app
```

It generated `app.routing.module.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old command. Since you are using the newest version. Simply run it

```
ionic start myapp blank
```

From https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/start
"Use the --type option to start projects using **older** versions of Ionic. For example, you can start an Ionic 3 project with --type=ionic-angular."

[image: start]
[image: finish]