# app-routing.module.ts and app.module.ts files are missing in Ionic project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm setting up a new ionic project using the following command :

```
ionic start
```

After that I chose Angular framework and blank project.

When the project is created it's missing `app-routing.module.ts` and `app.module.ts` files, there is only `app.routes.ts` file.
What have changed? Can someone explain me what can I do to get back those missing files?

My ionic version is **5.4.16**

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937786/the-app-routing-module-ts-file-missing-in-ionic-project

Comment: I just realized that a new version of Ionic came out and it pulled version 7 and apparently that's the difference in the files!

Comment: can you post that as an answer so it can help others as well

Answer (score 4):

After doing a week of head scratching IO7 supports using A14+

Here's Angular's upgrade guide link:
https://update.angular.io/
and the 'standalone' story of why and what to do:
https://angular.io/guide/standalone-migration
https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

The '`standalone: true`' in the Angular Component specifies their dependencies directly instead of getting them from **NgModule**

The days of launching '`ionic start`' and expecting `app.module.ts` in the folder structure are no longer!

I haven't used the migration tool yet, but this is supposed to automate the transition for old projects. So now it's the new paradigm of standalone components. Angular classes marked as standalone do not need to be declared in an **NgModule**(the Angular compiler will report an error if you try).

Comment: so no need to route or module any more ? its work perfectly ?

Answer (score 2):

If **app-routing.module.ts** and **app.module.ts** files are missing then

```
ng new testAng --no-standalone --routing --ssr=false
```

Hope it helps. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is new version of Ionic 7 and if I understand good enough, they decided to use Angular Standalone Component Routing.

Answer (score 0):

import your modules directly into your component, add the standalone option to true. thats the new upgrade for angular.

find example below

```
@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    standalone   : true, <==========
    imports      : [MatIconModule, FormsModule] <==========
})
```